# How to read an expression with sup and inf

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $K:H \to H$ be a linear operator on a Hilbert space $H$. The action of $K$ on any  $u$  is denoted by $Ku$.

I define the domain of $K$ as the set $D(K)$ of all $u \in H$ with the property that $Ku$ is in $H$.

Below, $u$ and $v$ are in $H$.

How do I have to read the below expression?

[image]

Changing $u$ I have to find the sup of the expression, but changing $v$ I have to find the inf of the expression.  Do I have to find the sup or the inf of the expression? How can I satisfy sup and inf at the same time?

Comment: I think you have to solve a minimization problem in the variable $v$ and a maximization problem in the variable $u$

Comment: When you have things of the form $\sup_x \inf_y f(x,y)$, for some function/formula $f(x,y)$ on the variables $x$ and $y$, you should think as: First define, for all $x$, $F(x)=\inf _y f(x,y)$ (to calculate each $F(x)$, the term "$x$" is fixed). Now we take $\sup_x F(x)$ (which makes sense since you know what $F(x)$ is for all $x$). The same applies if we had any other combination of $\sup$ and $\inf$. Sometimes they commute (i.e., $\sup_x\inf_y f(x)=\inf_y\sup_x f(x,y)$), but not in general.

Comment: Very clear answer. Thanks very much Luiz Cordeiro!

Answer (score 0):

As said by Luiz Cordeiro you have to solve the minimization problem in the first variable  and then the maximization problem in the second one.

So if you want $inf_x sup_y f(x,y)$  you have to compute  $s(x) = arg~ sup_y f_x(y)$ and then $inf_{x} f_{s(x)}(x)$